# Edit nodes in result with certain values

Tags: xml, powershell, nodes

Hi im trying to read my nodes from a xml in powershell.
Then i have to find the Invalid Nodes (when `ArrayDimensions` is available and Childnode got `ReferenceType`= "HasComponent```. Then i want to delete this Node from my Result.
Code:

```
[xml]$uar = Get-Content -Path '.\OpcUaMap(3)_28_07.uar'

$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($uar.NameTable)

$ns=@{test="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd";
    ua="ua="http://xxx/NodeSet.xsd";
    xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    uax="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd";
    xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    pv="http://yyy/NodeSet.xsd"}

$result=Select-xml -xml $uar -xpath "//test:UAVariable[contains(@NodeId,'ns=1;s=::')][starts-with(@DataType,'i=')]" -namespace $ns  | select -ExpandProperty node

write host $result

$result | ConvertTo-Html`
 -Property DataType, NodeId `
 > ".\result.html"
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UANodeSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:uax="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd" xmlns:ua="http://xxx/NodeSet.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pv="http://yyy/NodeSet.xsd" xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd">
    <UAObject NodeId="ns=1;s=::" BrowseName="1:::">
        <DisplayName>&lt;Default&gt;</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">ns=2;i=10001</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes" IsForward="false">ns=2;i=20001</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes">ns=1;s=::Program</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:ObjectExtension>
                    <ACL>
                        <ACE Role="1" Allow="0x017F"/>
                        <ACE Role="2" Allow="0x015F"/>
                    </ACL>
                </pv:ObjectExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAObject>
    <UAObject ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV" BrowseName="1:Global PV">
        <DisplayName>Global PV</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=61</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes" IsForward="false">ns=1;s=::</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen</Reference>
        </References>
    </UAObject>
    <UAVariable DataType="ns=1;i=100000" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug" BrowseName="1:gFahrzeug" AccessLevel="3" ValueRank="-1">
        <DisplayName>gFahrzeug</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">ns=1;i=100005</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gFahrzeug"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="ns=1;i=100010" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug" BrowseName="1:Kraftfahrzeug" AccessLevel="3" ValueRank="-1">
        <DisplayName>Kraftfahrzeug</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">ns=1;i=100015</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.PKW</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=3" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW" BrowseName="1:LKW" AccessLevel="3" ValueRank="1" ArrayDimensions="2">
        <DisplayName>LKW</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=63</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[0]</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[1]</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=3" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[0]" BrowseName="1:LKW[0]" AccessLevel="3">
        <DisplayName>LKW[0]</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=63</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <ACL>
                        <ACE Role="1" Allow="0x017F"/>
                        <ACE Role="2" Allow="0x015F"/>
                    </ACL>
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[0]"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=3" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[1]" BrowseName="1:LKW[1]" AccessLevel="3">
        <DisplayName>LKW[1]</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=63</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <ACL>
                        <ACE Role="1" Allow="0x017F"/>
                        <ACE Role="2" Allow="0x015F"/>
                    </ACL>
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[1]"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
</UANodeSet>
```

My Result is:

```
DataType        : i=3
ParentNodeId    : ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug
NodeId          : ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW
BrowseName      : 1:LKW
AccessLevel     : 3
ValueRank       : 1
ArrayDimensions : 2
DisplayName     : LKW
References      : References
Extensions      : Extensions

DataType     : i=3
ParentNodeId : ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW
NodeId       : ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[0]
BrowseName   : 1:LKW[0]
AccessLevel  : 3
DisplayName  : LKW[0]
References   : References
Extensions   : Extensions

DataType     : i=3
ParentNodeId : ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW
NodeId       : ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[1]
BrowseName   : 1:LKW[1]
AccessLevel  : 3
DisplayName  : LKW[1]
References   : References
Extensions   : Extensions
```

so its working.
Now i want to erase invalid Value like `ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW` because this is the declaration of the array and its invalid to be displayed.
How i have to get rid of it:
Every node `Displayname` but not all got `Arraydimensions`
so if `Arraydimensions` is available (not emtpy) and `ReferenceType` got a Value in in its a invalid node.
I have tried is something with
EDIT:

```
$result | foreach {
    $AttExists = $_.Arraydimensions
    $NodeExists = $_.ReferenceType
    if ($AttExists){
        if ($NodeExists = 'HasComponent'){
            Write-Host 'Delete'
        }
        else{
            Write-Host 'OK'
        }
    }
    else{
        Write-Host 'OK'
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Delete
OK
OK
OK
Delete
OK
OK
OK
Delete
OK
OK
```

it seems he didnt look in my referencetype for "HasComponent" because the last delete is wrong
It should be this:

```
Delete
OK
OK
OK
Delete
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
```

Comment: I get **foreach : Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method named 'HasAttributes'.** with your code. What am I missing? You also appear to be attempting to change the same variable you are iterating with your last code block. Perhaps it should be **else{$_ = $null**

Comment: yes ure right is there another way to check if my node has this attribute?

Comment: ok seems `$_.Arraydimensions -ne ""` is working how can i address the childnode "Displayname" and any other childnode?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to do. Are you just trying to blank the line that says **ArrayDimensions : 2**

Comment: no if a node has the ArrayDimensions and the Displayname hasnt got [] then its a declaration of the array and i dont want to have it

Comment: Does “I don’t want to have it” mean remove the element? What do you want to end up with? Perhaps if you can show your desired outcome it may help determining what you want and therefore what to do.

Comment: Ok my result above just without the hole first node. "remove the element?" Yes i want to remove it

Comment: Btw thanks for your patience im totally new to powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can remove the desired node.

```
[xml]$uar = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test.uar -Encoding UTF8

[xml]$uar = Get-Content -Path '.\OpcUaMap(3)_28_07.uar'

$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($uar.NameTable)

$ns=@{
    test="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd";
    ua="http://xxx/NodeSet.xsd";
    xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    uax="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd";
    xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    pv="http://yyy/NodeSet.xsd"
}

$result = Select-xml -xml $uar -xpath "//test:UAVariable[contains(@NodeId,'ns=1;s=::')][starts-with(@DataType,'i=')]" -namespace $ns  | select -ExpandProperty node

$nodetodelete = $result | where {$_.hasattribute("ArrayDimensions")}

$nodetodelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild($nodetodelete)
```

It should show you the node that got removed. If you want to suppress that output you can just assign the output to $null

```
$null = $nodetodelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild($nodetodelete)
```

You can also confirm it's removed by rerunning your query and confirming there are only 2 now.

```
Select-xml -xml $uar -xpath "//test:UAVariable[contains(@NodeId,'ns=1;s=::')][starts-with(@DataType,'i=')]" -namespace $ns  | select -ExpandProperty node
```

or

```
Select-xml -xml $uar -xpath "//test:UAVariable[contains(@NodeId,'ns=1;s=::')][starts-with(@DataType,'i=')]" -namespace $ns  | measure | select -expand count
```

Comment: Ok works fine an to the "ArrayDimensions" can i also delete when this node got a childnode with "ReferenceType". i mean ArrayDimensions and ReferenceType

Comment: Both have to be there to be removed?

Comment: Only if the node has Arraydimension and Referencetype yes. I have found this in the OuterXml of result is there a way to get it and looking if its empty?

Comment: I would simply change **$nodetodelete = $result | where {$_.hasattribute("ArrayDimensions")}** to **$nodetodelete = $result | where {$_.hasattribute("ArrayDimensions") -and $_.hasattribute("ReferenceType")}** except I don't see ReferenceType. Do you mean References?

Comment: yes inside references is the attribute ReferenceType

Comment: So you only want to remove the node of arraydimensions Is present and if references has the value ReferenceType? Why don’t you edit your post and add these details?

Comment: ok i think i got it **$NodeExists = $_.References.Reference.ReferenceType** so i can find this and with your code i can delete this